# How to get UITableView last scroll position before show next UIViewController?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a question about `UITableView`.

Because I want to save the `UITableView` last position in my `userdefault` before showing next `UIViewController`.

And when I back to homePage I can read userdefault value to auto scroll to my saving position.

Why I ask this question, because when I back to homePage I'll refresh my `viewcontroller` and the layout will change, so I can't get exactly position before showing.

Have any idea to me?
Thanks

Comment: Isn't this how it already works by default?

Comment: Use `tableView.contentOffset`.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Because when I back to homePage I'll refresh my viewcontroller and the layout will change, so I can't get exactly position before showing.

Comment: @Kamran Have example to me? Thanks.

Comment: @JimmyLee lookup `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `contentOffset`.

Save it on leaving:

```
float savedVerticalContentOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y;
```

and then when you return and refresh just call:

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, savedVerticalContentOffset)];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the index path of the first visible cell with `indexPathsForVisibleRows` and store that.  Then when you show the table again you could use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` to make sure that cell is visible.